# from complex xml to "flat" structure

Tags: xslt

Please, I'm trying to extract "plain text" from "annotated text" (or plain content from complex content).

This is the input XML I have:

```
<l>string</l>
<l>string<g><b/>string2</g></l>
<l>string<g><b/>string2</b>string3</g></l>
<l>string<b/>string2<b/>string3</l>
```

and this is the output I need:

```
<word>string</word>
<word>string1 string2</word>
<word>string1 string2 string3</word>
<word>string1 string2 string3</word>
```

Essentially: (i) I do not need the  element and (ii) replace empty  elements by blank spaces

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by making use of the identity transform, but overridding it with your special cases, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

   <!-- Replace elements under root element with word element -->
   <xsl:template match="/*/*">
      <word>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </word>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Match, but don't copy, elements -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Copy out text nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Replace empty element by space -->
   <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]">
      <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on the following XML

```
<data>
   <l>string</l>
   <l>string<g><b/>string2</g></l>
   <l>string<g><b/>string2<b/>string3</g></l>
   <l>string<b/>string2<b/>string3</l>
</data>
```

The output is as follows:

```
<word>string</word>
<word>string string2</word>
<word>string string2 string3</word>
<word>string string2 string3</word>
```

Comment: Good, +1. Any particular reason why you output non-breaking spaces?

Comment: @LarsH Nope, there was no particular reason! I had just used an existing XSLT file on my PC as the starting point, and it just so happened to have a non-breaking space in that.